# How to animate buttons to travel out of view bounds

Tags: swift, animation, uibutton

In my home screen I have a series of buttons that are centre-aligned: New game, how to play, continue game.

When clicked I want to animate the buttons to linearly move out of the screen sideways. One of the buttons (the rest very similar) has the following constraints (using auto-layout):

```
Align Center X to: Safe Area
Align Center Y to: Safe Area, Multiplier 1.2
Proportional width 0.6 with Superview
300:50 Ratio: to Button
```

I'd thought the following code would provide the desired animation but doesn't appear to work:

```
 button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 1000)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1, usingSpringWithDamping: 4, initialSpringVelocity: 4, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded()}, completion: nil)
```

Any suggestions on how to get the button to animate so that it moves sideways out of the screen much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: the buttons to animate in forward to each other they should be hook with leadings and trailings , not centerX for all , that's ig you'll control animation from of them , horizental stackview is perfect for that animation

Answer (score 1):

Simply this

```
button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 1000)
```

will create another constraint , and will cause a conflict , so when you create the original centerX hold it in a var like

```
var centerCon:NSLayoutConstraint! 
centerCon = button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0) 
centerCon.isActive = true
```

Then play with it's constant value

```
 centerCon.constant =  1000
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1, usingSpringWithDamping: 4, initialSpringVelocity: 4, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded()}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.  Doesn't have all your extra springy params, but maybe it's helpful:

```
amountToTranslateBy = self.view.bounds.width // assuming this is executed from inside ViewController

UIView.animate(withDuration: yourDuration, delay: yourDelay, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                        for view in yourArrayOfViews {
                            view.center.x -= amountToTranslateBy
                        }

                    }, completion: nil)
```

The constraints that you've set shouldn't be effected by this animation especially since the buttons' constraints are dependent on other (super) views not vice-versa.  As long as you remember move the views back to their original place (+= amountToTranslateBy) using the same methodology at the appropriate time it should be ok.